# How to interpret this SBT DSL?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm still new to Scala and the build tool SBT. In the official getting started guide for SBT, I encountered the following example of `build.sbt`.

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "hello"
  )
```

The DSL looks like some sort of scripting language, but I'm still struggling to understand what's going on. My questions are:

1. What is `file(".")`? Does it return a list of files in current directory?
2. Is the statement `project in file(".")` a for-in loop expression?
3. Why does `root` has to be annotated with `lazy`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is file(".")? Does it return a list of files in current
>   directory?

`file(".")` returns an `sbt.File` type, which is an alias for the `java.io.File` type, [which describes a file/directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). The dot refers to the top level project, or the relative path to which the current file/directory resides:

```
scala> import java.io._
import java.io._

scala> val f = new File(".")
f: java.io.File = .

scala> f.getAbsolutePath
res0: String = C:\Users\MyUser\.

scala> f.isDirectory
res1: Boolean = true
```

> Is the statement project in file(".") a for-in loop expression?

No. It's a simple method call, equivalent to `project.in(file("."))`. Scala has a feature called ["infix notation"](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html), which allows you to call a method of arity 0 or 1 without the `.`

> Why does root has to be annotated with lazy?

It doesn't have it be. `lazy` in Scala defers the allocation of a variable to the first time someone calls it, instead of allocating it beforehand during constructor initialization.